# Possessive Noun Apostrophes

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm struggling a bit with an apostrophe question - I have the clause, "Using the example of the singer Michael Jackson’s death", which I'm pretty sure isn't right as there should probably be a comma after "singer", but the apostrophe doesn't look right there either and I'm not sure how to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Proofreading questions are off-topic here; I am not sure if this would be welcome on English SE. I will flag for the mods to ask.

Comment: It's fine as it is. The apostrophe is required, and no comma is required after "singer" since "Michael Jackson" is an integrated (defining) appositive NP, not a supplementary (non-defining) one.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you have there is correct.

Not sure why it doesn't look right to you, but it is right.